# Session lock. session_write_close() doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, session

The topic of session lock is quite much discussed already and I'm aware of "magic" `session_write_close()` function. However...

I have an Ajax call, which performs pretty long operation (takes several minutes). In order to have a progress information I run another Ajax call every 10 seconds. However I see all those calls are pending and start being processed when main long call is finished. In Apache status I see those calls are in working state.

I have `session_write_close()` call in first script. Using Xdebug I've traced execution of the script and ensured `session_write_close()` is called as a last session related operation and no `start_session()` is called afterwards. However all consequent calls are still stalled.

What else might I miss?

Comment: There's no "magic" in `session_write_close()` - it releases the lock and closes the session (meaning it closes e.g. the file descriptor if you're using file-based sessions). I'm saying this because it's important to know what a function does if you'll be using it - don't ever rely on "magic"!

Comment: By "magic" I rather meant it was a most recommended way to solve session lock :-)

Comment: Well, "magic" should never be recommended and session locks are a solution, not a problem. :) I won't bother you with more comments, but I will reiterate once more what I wanted to say initially - you need to know how (and why) something works before using it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem wasn't related to session lock. I have noticed the long-running script consumed together with MySQL 100% of CPU. Because it's not production server I had only one CPU assigned to the VM. I've added second CPU to VM and the problem has gone!